# PHP WSDL NuSoap ComplexType array of itself

Tags: php, arrays, wsdl, nusoap, complextype

This is what I want to do:

```
// Pull in the NuSOAP code
require_once('nusoap.php');
// Create the server instance
$server = new soap_server();

// Initialize WSDL support
$server->configureWSDL('server', 'urn:server');

$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'FilterObject',
    'complexType',
    'struct',
    'all',
    '',
    array(
        'myName' => array('name' => 'myName', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
        'filter' => array('name' => 'filter', 'type' => 'tns:FilterObject[]')
    )
);
```

I want to have an array of FilterObject in itself so that I can have this structure.

```
<myName></myName>
<FilterObject>
    <myName></myName>
    <FilterObject>
        <myName></myName>
        <FilterObject>Value</FilterObject>
        <FilterObject>
            <myName></myName>
            <FilterObject>Value</FilterObject>
            <FilterObject>Value</FilterObject>
            ...
        </FilterObject>
        <FilterObject>Value</FilterObject>
        <FilterObject>Value</FilterObject>
        <FilterObject>Value</FilterObject>
        <FilterObject>Value</FilterObject>
        ...
    </FilterObject>
</FilterObject>
```

HOW can I achieve this?

I have been struggling now for almost 2 days. I have searched the web and came to no conclusion. Please help.

Edit:

This is how I did it. Thanks to Alex.

I did not think that it's possible to do this, as I thought that I would create a circular reference.

What I also noted was that the "FilterObjectArray" is not visible as a class object when pulled into C#, although "FilterObject" is available. This is obviously because the array is just a parameter that is set on top of the "FilterObject" object, making it an array.

Hope this makes sense.

```
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'FilterObject',
    'complexType',
    'struct',
    'all',
    '',
    array(
        'myName' => array('name' => 'myName', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
        'filter' => array('name' => 'filter', 'type' => 'tns:FilterObjectArray')
    )
);

$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'FilterObjectArray',  // Name
    'complexType',    // Type Class
    'array',          // PHP Type
    '',               // Compositor
    'SOAP-ENC:Array', // Restricted Base
    array(),
    array(
        'children' => array('ref' => 'SOAP-ENC:arrayType', 'wsdl:arrayType' => 'tns:FilterObject[]'),
    ),
    'tns:FilterObject'
);
```

Comment: Can't you just create an array complexType that holds FilterObjets?